# Is it good idea to generate random string until success with "crypto/rand"?

Tags: go, random, hex

Is it a good idea to generate a secure random hex string until the process succeeds?

All examples I've come across show that if `rand.Read` returns error, we should panic, os.Exit(1) or return empty string and the error.

I need my program to continue to function in case of such errors and wait until a random string is generated. Is it a good idea to loop until the string is generated, any pitfalls with that?

```
import "crypto/rand"

func RandomHex() string {
    var buf [16]byte
    for {
        _, err := rand.Read(buf[:])
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    return hex.EncodeToString(buf[:])
}
```

Comment: `math/rand` or `crypto/rand`?

Comment: crypto/rand @RayfenWindspear

Comment: I believe the answer to your question lies in the documentation for the particular platform you are on and the specific random source's documentation for what errors it can return. Go directly calls what is available via the operating system. See https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/rand.go#L19

Comment: @maerics sad, if this is consistently the case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to loop until the string is generated,

That depends. Probably yes.

> any pitfalls with that?

You discard the random bytes read on error. And this in a tight loop.
This may drain you entropy source (depending on the OS) faster than
it can be filled.

Instead of an unbound infinite loop: Break after n rounds and give up.
Graceful degradation or stopping is best: If your program is stuck in
an endless loop it is also not "continue"ing.

Comment: Finally I decided to go with a slightly different choice: instead of retrying the same method, if error occurs the first time on `rand.Read`, I'll try to generate MD5 hex string with some pseudorandom data from `math/rand`, which should never fail.

Comment: @luben Do not forget to seed math/rand with something real random on startup.

Answer (score 3):

No. It may always return an error in certain contexts.

Example: [playground: don't use /dev/urandom in crypto/rand](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5096)

Imagine that a machine does not have the source that crypto/rand gets data from or the program runs in a context that doesn't have access to that source. In that case you might consider having the program return that error in a meaningful way rather than spin.

More explicitly, if you are serious in your use of `crypto/rand` then consider writing `RandomHex` such that it is exceptionally clear to the caller that it is meant for security contexts (possibly rename it) and return the error from `RandomHex`. The calling function needs to handle that error and let the user know that something is very wrong. For example in a rest api, I'd expect that error to surface to the request handler, fail & return a 500 at that point, and log a high severity error.

Comment: If the PRNG source is not available or has failed for some reason, the admin absolutely needs to know this immediately. Failing fast is the right thing to do. The problem with the PRNG needs to be fixed before attempting to run any program that needs it. Letting the program spin in a loop doesn't tell anybody that there is a problem, or could cause them to misidentify the problem.

Comment: Thank you, both answers helped me to implement it better.